# mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch Library:100005

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've got a rather tricky problem with my webserver since I performed a regular package update last Friday. I'm getting an error when using mysql_connect().

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50532 Library:100005 in /srv/www/***/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1142
```

When I run php -i I get:

```
mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 10.0.5-MariaDB  
Client API header version => 5.5.32
```

apt-get install mariadb*

Results in the following packages already installed:

```
libmariadbclient18 is already the newest version.
libmariadbclient18 set to manually installed.
mariadb-client is already the newest version.
mariadb-client-10.0 is already the newest version.
mariadb-client-10.0 set to manually installed.
mariadb-client-core-10.0 is already the newest version.
mariadb-client-core-10.0 set to manually installed.
mariadb-common is already the newest version.
mariadb-common set to manually installed.
mariadb-server is already the newest version.
mariadb-server-10.0 is already the newest version.
mariadb-server-10.0 set to manually installed.
mariadb-server-core-10.0 is already the newest version.
mariadb-server-core-10.0 set to manually installed.
```

I've already looked up this issue all over the web, but none of the similar issues seem to have the -MariaDB tag with the library version.

So I've no idea how I can resolve this.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

edit:

php -i mysql:

```
MySQL Support => enabled
Client API version => 10.0.5-MariaDB
```

Oddly enought there is no mention of a Client API library version or
Client API header version in this section.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thanks for the tip, I updated the mysql details in the topic. It's strange that the client and library versions are not mentioned in this section of the php info.

Comment: I'd suggest installing the mysqlnd package for PHP.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks! that removed the error! Now to figure out how I got that issue in the first place...

Comment: @SonicFC: It's not really an error so much as a warning.  It's simply saying the versions don't match, so you *may* have problems.  It's because MariaDB updated to version 10, where Oracle MySQL is still 5.x.

Answer (score 3):

Install the `mysqlnd` package for PHP and the warning should go away.

For **Debian/Ubuntu** based systems, this would be:

```
sudo apt install php-mysqlnd
```

or

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mysqlnd
```

Restart your server daemons after installing (apache, nginx, and/or php-fpm)

Comment: @danorton :/ did you remember to restart your webserver daemons (apache, nginx, php-fpm) after installing?

Comment: The installation takes care of that itself.

Comment: Additionally, phpmyadmin requires php5-mysql.

Answer (score 3):

Enable the **mysqlnd**, **nd_mysql**, and **nd_mysqli** extentions for PHP, and disable mysql and mysqli if they are enabled (PHP 5.5).

Late response, but this is high in the search results and this is the solution that worked for me, as someone who did not have admin access to the server.

Comment: That solved my problem as well. But I also had to add @ before the mysqli_connect statement. Thanks @coin